# Como comparar con mas de un parámetro?

Tags: javascript

Hola a todos como podria comparar mas de un parametro que recibo en una funcion ?
Tengo una función que recibe un array de **strings** con nombre de peliculas que estan de estrenos;

```
    peliculasEstreno = ['Cars', 'The Witcher', 'Shrek'];

    function pelis(peliculasEstreno) {}
```

**Y**  tengo un array de objetos con distintas propiedades. Lo que tengo que hacer es **comparar** los nombres que están dentro del array que me pasan en la funcion como parametro y si la propiedad **nombre** coincide, cambiar la propiedad **estreno** a true.

```
 const peliculas = [
       {
        nombre: 'Top Gun: Maverick',
        Estreno: '2022',
        genero: 'Acción/Drama',
        estreno: false,
      },
      {
        nombre: 'Amnesia',
        añoDeEstreno: '2000',
        genero: 'Acción',
        estreno: false,
      },
      {
        nombre: 'Avengers: La era de Ultrón',
        añoDeEstreno: '2015',
        genero: 'Fantasia/Aventura/Acción',
        estreno: false,
      },
    ];
```

Se como hacerlo con una sola propiedad osea si no fuera un array asi:

```
 function pelis(peliculasEstreno){
   for (let i = 0; i < peliculas.length; i++) {
     if(peliculas[i].nombre === peliculasEstreno){
         peliculas[i].estreno = true
     }
   }

   return pelisEstreno
 }
```

Ayuda plis!!

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que compares los elementos del array `peliculas` con el array `peliculasEstreno`, tendrías que también ingresar a los elementos de `peliculasEstreno`, y para ello se tendría que hacer otro ciclo `for` dentro para recorrer el array con quien deseas comparar, y pues con esto ya lo obtendrías. Ejemplo:

```js
let peliculasEstreno = ['Cars', 'The Witcher', 'Shrek'];

let peliculas = [
  {
    nombre: 'Top Gun: Maverick',
    Estreno: '2022',
    genero: 'Acción/Drama',
    estreno: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Amnesia',
    añoDeEstreno: '2000',
    genero: 'Acción',
    estreno: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Avengers: La era de Ultrón',
    añoDeEstreno: '2015',
    genero: 'Fantasia/Aventura/Acción',
    estreno: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Cars',
    añoDeEstreno: '2018',
    genero: 'Acción/Drama',
    estreno: false, // pongo false para modificarlo, ya que "Cars" existe en el array.
  }
];

function pelis(peliculasEstreno, peliculas) {
  for (let i = 0; i < peliculas.length; i++) { // recorro al array de objetos "peliculas"
    for (let j = 0; j < peliculasEstreno.length; j++) { // y también recorro al array "peliculasEstreno", que es el array con quien quiero comparar
      if (peliculas[i].nombre === peliculasEstreno[j]) { // ingreso a los dos arrays y comparo, si cumple...
        peliculas[i].estreno = true; // cambio el estado.
      }
    }
  }

  return peliculas; // y retorno el array modificado.
}

console.log(pelis(peliculasEstreno, peliculas))
```

Comment: Si me funciono gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Explicación en comentarios:

```js
let peliculasEstreno = ['Cars', 'The Witcher', 'Shrek'];

let peliculas = [
  {
    nombre: 'Top Gun: Maverick',
    Estreno: '2022',
    genero: 'Acción/Drama',
    estreno: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Amnesia',
    añoDeEstreno: '2000',
    genero: 'Acción',
    estreno: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Avengers: La era de Ultrón',
    añoDeEstreno: '2015',
    genero: 'Fantasia/Aventura/Acción',
    estreno: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Cars',
    añoDeEstreno: '2018',
    genero: 'Acción/Drama',
    estreno: false, 
  }
];



function pelis(peliculasEstreno, peliculas) {

  // 1. Convertir el arreglo de `peliculsasEstreno` en un diccionario para 
  // hacer más eficiente la búsqueda
  peliculasDic = Object.fromEntries(peliculasEstreno.map(p => [p, true]))
  
  // iterar las peliculas, se usa forEach por se más compacto
  // se busca la pelicula en el diccionario `peliculasDic[pelicula.nombre]` si se encuentra
  // el valor devuelto es true de lo contrario será undefined y se convierte en false
  // evaluando con el operador ??
  peliculas.forEach(pelicula => pelicula.estreno = peliculasDic[pelicula.nombre] ?? false)

  return peliculas; 
}

console.log(pelis(peliculasEstreno, peliculas))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!